# Some product pages layout issue Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, error, product-page, console

Suddenly my site has suffering layout issue on some product pages. I checked in console and it says require is not a defined, but many other product pages and site is working fine.
[image]

Comment: It's your custom js issue, if you've implemented any js so that's the cause of this issue.

Comment: But other pdp's are working fine. The issue is in some product pages. Also I checked by duplicating the product having issue, and the duplicated product was working fine.

Comment: Check the sources by different pages as you said error page source with non-error page source and that may help you

Comment: did you try in incognito mode? Maybe these pages were cached in the browser or in the varnish. Not sure just a hint.

Comment: It is done. It was some deployment issue. I ran the commands again and it was solved. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by running all commands setup:upgrade, di:compile, static-content and indexing. Then deleting folders generated/code and var/cache, var/page_cache.